# Vaadin into Angular v1.x with through Webpack bundle

Tags: angularjs, webpack, vaadin, webpack-dev-server

I am trying to bundle Vaadin in a single file to be loaded inside my portal (which running with AngularJS V1.x) following [this guide](https://vaadin.com/learn/tutorials/using-web-components). It fails because is using an old configuration (which I fixed for the development mode but I didn't for the production one) and because I could bundle the references left in the node modules instead of copied inside the bundle.

So I tried with a new webpack setup with this configuration:

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');


var config = {
  // TODO: Add common Configuration
  mode: 'development',
  performance: {
    hints: false,
    maxEntrypointSize: 5512000,
    maxAssetSize: 5512000
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist',
  },
  module: {}
};

var jsConfig = Object.assign({}, config, {
  entry: {
    index: './src/index.js',
    vaadin: './src/webcomponentsjs/main.js'
  },
  optimization: {
    minimize: true
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'Vaadin Library',
      template: './src/index.html'
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.LimitChunkCountPlugin({
      maxChunks: 1,
    })
  ],
  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    clean: false
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
            plugins: ['transform-class-properties']
          }
        }
      }
    ],
  }
});

module.exports = [
  jsConfig
];
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "webpack-demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.6",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-top-level-await": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-template-literals": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.5",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^5.2.6",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.1",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^1.6.0",
    "npm": "^7.17.0",
    "sass": "^1.35.1",
    "sass-loader": "^12.1.0",
    "script-ext-html-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.5",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack": "^5.39.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.7.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "echo \"Bundling Vaadin library to less files and convert to ES5 with Webpack and Babel (loader)\" && webpack",
    "start": "webpack serve --open"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

And here the errors (for each component imported in index.js):

ERROR in ./src/index.js 2:0-31
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@vaadin/vaadin-button' in '/Users/username/Dev/current/webpack-vaadin/src'
Did you mean './@vaadin/vaadin-button'?
Requests that should resolve in the current directory need to start with './'.
Requests that start with a name are treated as module requests and resolve within module directories (node_modules).
If changing the source code is not an option there is also a resolve options called 'preferRelative' which tries to resolve these kind of requests in the current directory too.

[image]

Did anyone already manage to import Vaadin into an angularJs application? How did you do or could you point me at the right place in the documentation (which I didn't find as very new with this FW)?

Thanks in advance.